# Adding multiple on click listeners for several buttons

Tags: java, android, button, onclicklistener

How can you make it so that user can have several buttons with on click listeners. I tried it with 2 buttons, but it said that I had already defined the on-click listener so I could not make another on click listener as a result. The code I have so far is:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private View btnRender;
    private LinearLayout container;
    private View btnRendered;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnRender = (View)findViewById(R.id.btn_render);
        container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.fragment_layout);
        btnRendered = (View) findViewById(R.id.btn_rendered);

        //set event handling for button
        btnRender.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());
    }

    private View.OnClickListener onClickListener() {


        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //replace fragment when clicked
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, new PDFRenderFragment());
                ft.commit();

                //gone button after all
                btnRender.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        };


       }
}
```

The `btn_rendered` is the other button that  I want to set an on click listener for, but the software will not let me do this. Is it true that I need to set up a switch-case method for it to work?

I just tried out both codes and none of them seem to have doen the desired effect. Now whenever I click one of the buttons, the 2nd pdf always shows! (what I was using the button for)

Comment: Add the code for that button too. And show the compile error.

Comment: That sounds strange.Can you post the code you tried to add the second listener on the other button?

Comment: `btnRender.setVisibility(View.GONE);`. So you want to hide that button when the other button is pressed?

Comment: that is exactly what I want it to do

Answer (score 1):

You can handle like below.

```
btnRender.setOnClickListener(onClickListener()); 
btnRendered.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());

 private View.OnClickListener onClickListener() {


        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                switch(v.getId()){
                case R.id.btn_render:
                //replace fragment when clicked
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, new PDFRenderFragment());
                ft.commit();

                //gone button after all
                btnRender.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                break; 
                case R.id.btn_rendered:
                // your logic here 

                break; 
            }
          }
        };
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use same method for second button too and use if/else condition for identify which button is click in that method.
like below code.

```
//set event handling for button
 btnRender.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());
 second_btn.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());
```

Your **onClickListener** Method.

```
private View.OnClickListener onClickListener() {


        return new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //replace fragment when clicked
                if (v == btnRender) {
                    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_layout, new PDFRenderFragment());
                    ft.commit();

                    //gone button after all
                    btnRender.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    container.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else if (v == second_btn) {
                    //second button click code
                }
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much!